# Hilbert bundle and set of sections.

Tags: functional-analysis, differential-geometry, hilbert-spaces, operator-algebras, noncommutative-geometry

Let $\Lambda$ be a manifold and $p:H\to\Lambda$ a continuous Hilbert bundle with $H(\lambda):=p^{-1}(\lambda)$. Suppose $\Gamma_0^0(\Lambda)$ is the space of continuous sections vanishing at infinity of $H$. I proved that $\Gamma_0^0(\Lambda)$ has the structure of a $C_0(\Lambda)$ module (with $C_0$ being the space of continuous functions vanishing at infinity). Define $H_{\lambda}=\Gamma_0^0(\Lambda)/\overline{K_{\lambda}}$ where $$K_{\lambda}=\text{span}\{f\varphi:\varphi\in \Gamma_0^0(\Lambda)\text{ and } f(\lambda)=0\}$$
I am interested in showing that $H_{\lambda}$ i isomorphic to $H(\lambda)$. Does anyone know some way to prove this?

Comment: **Hint:** Consider the kernel of the evaluation map $\Gamma_0^0(\Lambda)\to H_\lambda$.

Comment: How do you relate $\overline{K_\lambda}$ with the Kernel? I'm sure $\overline{K_\lambda}$ contained in  the Kernel  but there is no equality between them.

Answer (score 1):

In a local trivialization of $\Lambda$ around $\lambda$, let $U_n$ be the open ball centered at $\lambda$ with radius $1/n$,
and use Uryhson to choose a continuous (bump) function $h_n$ on $\Lambda$ with $0≤h_n≤1$, vanishing off $U_n$ and  with
$h_n(\lambda)=1$.  It is then easy to  prove that for every section $\varphi$ vanishing at $\lambda$, one has that $\Vert h_n\varphi\Vert
\to 0$.

Setting $f_n:= 1-h_n$ we deduce that $\|\varphi - f_n\varphi\|\to0$.

The given definition of $K_\lambda$
does not specify exactly what kind of functions $f$ are used there, but assuming bounded continuous functions are OK, then we
are done because our $f_n$ above  clearly satisfies these properties.

Should one prefer to define $K_\lambda$ as
$$
  K_{\lambda}=\text{span}\{f\varphi:\varphi\in \Gamma_0^0(\Lambda)\text{, } f\in C_0(\Lambda) \text{ and } f(\lambda)=0\}
  $$
(mind you that $f$ is now required to be in $C_0(\lambda)$)
the above method will not work but it can be fixed as follows:

Using that $\varphi$ vanishes at $\infty$, one may show that there exists some $g$ in  $C_0(\Lambda)$ such that $\varphi$ is
near $g\varphi$.  It will then follow that $\varphi$ is near $f_ng\varphi$, and bingo, $f_ng$ now lies in $C_0(\Lambda)$ and vanishes at $\lambda$, so
$\varphi$ is seen to lie in the closure of the newly defined $K_\lambda$.